# SQL left joining multiple tables on multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

MS SQL Server.

I have 10 tables (table1, table2, table3,etc..) and I want to left join them and get a few fields from each table. Some tables need to be left joined on multiple fields, e.g. table1 and table2 need to be left joined on 3 fields.

Here is a sample from the script I tried to use but I get errors (I masked the real tables and fields name):

```
SELECT  table1.[Field1], 
        table1.[Field2],
        table1.[Field3],
        table1.[Field5],        
        table2.[Field1], 
        table2.[Field2], 
        table2.[Field3],  
        table3.[Field4],
            table4.[Field1], 
        table4.[Field4],
        table4.[Field5],        
        table5.[Field4],
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 As a
    on a.[Field1] = table2.[Field1]
LEFT JOIN table1 As b 
    on b.[Field3] = table2.[Field3]
LEFT JOIN table1 As c 
    on c.[Field2] = table2.[Field2]
LEFT JOIN table4 As d 
    on table1.[Field5] = d.[Field4]
LEFT JOIN table4 As e 
    on table1.[Field1] = e.[Field1]
LEFT JOIN table5 
    on table4.[Field4] = table5.[Field4]
LEFT JOIN table3 
    on table4.[Field4] = table3.[Field4];
```

Any "simple" way to do that?

Comment: what you meant by simple way of joining the tables.let us know what you have tried and what you desire to do.?

Comment: The post is now edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try This query .it may help you

```
 SELECT  table1.[Field1], 
        table1.[Field2],
        table1.[Field3],
        table1.[Field5],        
        table2.[Field1], 
        table2.[Field2], 
        table2.[Field3],  
        table3.[Field4], 
        table4.[Field4],
        table4.[Field5],        
        table5.[Field4],
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 As a on a.[Field1] = table2.[Field1]
and a.[Field3] = table2.[Field3]
and a.[Field2] = table2.[Field2]
LEFT JOIN table4 As d on table1.[Field5] = d.[Field4]
and table1.[Field1] = d.[Field1]
LEFT JOIN table5 on d.[Field4] = table5.[Field4]
LEFT JOIN table3 on d.[Field4] = table3.[Field4];
```

Answer (score 1):

`use NORTHWND;`
`go`

`select Orders.OrderID,Employees.EmployeeID,Employees.FirstName + '  ' +`
`Employees.LastName as "Full Name",Customers.CompanyName as "Customer Company Name",`
`Customers.ContactName as "Customers Contact Name",`
    `RegionDescription,Products.ProductName,[Order Details].UnitPrice,` `Suppliers.CompanyName as "Supplier Company Name"` 
`from Orders` 
`left join Customers` 
`on Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID` 
`left join Employees` 
    `on Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID` 
`left join EmployeeTerritories` 
    `on Employees.EmployeeID=EmployeeTerritories.EmployeeID` 
`join Territories` 
    `on Territories.TerritoryID=EmployeeTerritories.TerritoryID` 
`join Region`
    `on region.RegionID=Territories.RegionID` 
`join [Order Details]` 
    `on [Order Details].OrderID=Orders.OrderID` 
`join Products` 
    `on Products.ProductID=[Order Details].ProductID` 
`join Categories` 
    `on Categories.CategoryID=Products.CategoryID` 
`join Suppliers` 
    `on Suppliers.SupplierID=products.SupplierID`  
`where categories.CategoryID=1;`